FFmpeg MP4 command not working as expected
I’ve tried to use FFmpeg to prepare a video for YouTube, based on the YouTube recommended upload encoding settings but can’t make it work.
Does anyone know the exact encoding FFmpeg command based on this YouTube help page?
I’ve used this command, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong? Can you make it work?
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 320k -profile:v high -level 4.0 -bf 2 -coder 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 10M -threads 4 -cpu-used 0 -r 30 -g 15 -movflags +faststart out.mp4


What are you attempting to accomplish? Are you converting a file?

Create a .mp4 based on the link I sent because the command that I used does not work.

You spam "not working" in every sentence and title but it's far from clear what exactly is not working. Remember that by providing more details you don't only help future readers, but also potential answerers and yourself.

Part of your problem is that you have your commands in the wrong order. As a starting point, you should group your options into input -> processing -> output. There are exeptions to this and as you gain more experience, you can chain multiple inputs and outputs, but this is a starting point. Your command seems overkill for just overlaying a single image on an audio track.
The first problem I see is that the output chain is before the processing chain, so let's separate them out.
Start simple, and then you can add in options along the way.
So we can break it down to:
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -r 30 -i image.jpg \
-i audio.mp3 \
-c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 \
-c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 320k \
out.mp4

Now I can already see a problem here, and that is that the image input loop will generate a stream of undefined length, and so the processing will continue indefinitely. To fix this you could use -to 12:34.567 on the input side before the -i, you could use -to 12:34.567 on the output side before the -c:v, or, my favourite, -shortest, which will close the output when the shortest input has closed.
Looking at the rest of the arguments you have added in here:
-b:v 10M, which sets a fixed bitrate, will cause a policy clash with -crf 18, which sets a variable bitrate. How is ffmpeg supposed to know which one to follow?
-movflags +faststart are useful for content on your own website, but YouTube will add these in automatically when preparing your video for show, so you don't need to add these.
Each of the rest of your options can be added in one at a time, but consider whether you want them to take effect on the input chain or the output chain, and the -vf filter will go in-between them.
